# How to download qr code using NPM qr-code module in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, qr-code

I am geting DataUrl, now how can I download in Image format?

**I am geting this string:**

> data:image/png;base64,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

```
var segs = [
    { data: 'ABCDEFG', mode: 'alphanumeric' },
    { data: '0123456', mode: 'numeric' }
]
QRCode.toDataURL(segs, { errorCorrectionLevel: 'H', version:2 }, 
    function (err, url) {
        // QRCode.pipe(url);
        console.log(url)
});
```

**I have sent string to:**

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="qrcode">
```

Yes it is working for visual but I want to download it in png or jpeg format.

Comment: `png or jpeg` well, clearly you don't have that choice. Have you tried anything to actually download it?

Comment: What happens if you redirect to that base64 url?

Comment: 1.) You need to decode the base64 to a valid image binary
2.) Create a HTTP Server with vanilla js or express.js
3.) Download/View the file via a GET request

Comment: Yes, I have tried this `QRCode.pipe(url);`

Comment: Actually Url is a DataUrl it can work only in img tag `<img src="url"></img>`